# Book about humans stuck in a wormhole where reality is shaped by alien fungus; queer woman main character

Tags: story-identification, novel, space

A small group of humans has settled on a world where reality is shaped by thoughts, via a strange alien fungus that responds to the thoughts of the life forms around it.

The humans are stranded and it's implied they might be stuck in a wormhole. Everything made from the fungus disintegrates after a while, so their resources are running out. Lots of feelings of cold, emptiness, uneasiness, and a sense of time running out.

The POV character is a woman, and if I remember correctly she has a Russian name (I remembered her name being Vanya but couldn't find results searching for that name). Her relationship with another woman is a major plot point.

I'm pretty sure it was published in the 21st century by a female author. I read this via my public library years ago (around 2017) and I can't find anything like it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall the approximate year in which you read this? Feel free to give a range of years if you're not sure.

Comment: @LogicDictates I think it was 2017.

Comment: There's some similarities to C. J. Cherryh's [*Port Eternity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternate_Realities_(Cherryh)#Port_Eternity), but not a good enough match to propose as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like [*Amatka*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amatka) by Karin Tidbeck. Amatka was published in Swedish in 2012, and released in English in 2017.

The main character Vanja lives on a cold, desolate world where most objects are made of an alien fungus that only retains its shape when clearly labeled. The human population is stranded on the world, and has been for decades. Vanja's relationship to another woman is a central plot point.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if this is [Pushing Ice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushing_Ice) by Alastair Reynolds? Not all details match, but enough do that I'm throwing it out as an answer.

What matches:

1. The two main characters are both women: Bella Lind, mostly the POV character, and Svetlana (a Russian name) Barseghian. Their relationship is critical to the plot.
2. The humans spend the middle and last thirds of the novel stranded, in different places, and it's implied at the end they might be stuck in a wormhole. It was very ambiguous.
3. Resources are definitely running out. Lots of feelings of cold, emptiness, uneasiness, and a sense of time running out.
4. Published 21st century.

What doesn't match:

1. Male author.
2. No alien fungus or mind altering reality.